# Changing data source of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on an application which has `DataGridView` bound to a database.
Done simply by setting `datasource` property of `datagridview`.

As now I have to work on search feature so 
I get the data in a new data set and tried to bind the data source with the newly created dataset.

```
gridviewobj.datasource = newdataset;
```

but the data grid always appear as empty.
my data set contents the appropriate data.
still the problem arrives.

Please help

Comment: Please, post code sample, which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Did you do gridviewobj.DataBind() after assigning datasource?

Comment: `winform` or `asp.net`?

Comment: WinForms and i think there is no databind method here

Comment: @user3138481 Did u tried any of suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

To show the data we have to `bind` it as well after setting up the `datasource` (as "Naveen" mentioned in the comment):

```
gridviewobj.datasource = newdataset;
gridviewobj.DataBind();
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void GridBind(string StrQry="")
{
  string Qry = string.Empty;
  //StrQry = "Select * from tbl_Emp where Dept='Acc'";
  if (StrQry != string.Empty)
  {
    Qry = StrQry;
  }
  else 
  {
    Qry = "Select * from tbl_Emp";
  }

  Conn();

  Cmd = new SqlCommand(Qry,con);
  da = new SqldataAdapter(cmd);
  da.fil(dt);
  if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
  {
    gridviewobj.datasource = dt;
  }
}
```

Comment: As I am working on winforms,I dont think i have to use databind method.

Comment: sorry i think is asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the Table index, This will work if the columns are created dynamically.

```
gridviewobj.datasource = newdataset.Tables[0];
```

If you have already created the Grid columns manually through the Grid Edit wizard then you will have to go to properties of each column and set the `DataPropertyName` to relevant Database table column name to bind.